# Is unique index and standard index be done separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, database-indexes

I have this association table migration:

```
create_table :association_table do |t|
  t.belongs_to :table1, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.belongs_to :table2, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.datetime :deleted_at, index: true

  t.timestamps
end

add_index :association_table, [:table1_id, :table2_id], unique: true
```

This created five indexes for this particular table. Given that I already made the unique index for the tandem column of `[:table1_id, :table2_id]`, is it still necessary to add the separate index `index: true` on those 2 fields on which the purpose is to speed up the query? Or will the unique index do that job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting **uniq: true** refers to an index where all rows of the index must be unique. That is, the same row may not have identical non-NULL values for all columns in this index as another row. As well as being used to speed up queries, UNIQUE indexes can be used to enforce restraints on data, because the database system does not allow this distinct values rule to be broken when inserting or updating data.

Your database system may allow a UNIQUE index to be applied to columns which allow NULL values, in which case two rows are allowed to be identical if they both contain a NULL value (the rationale here is that NULL is considered not equal to itself). Depending on your application, however, you may find this undesirable: if you wish to prevent this, you should disallow NULL values in the relevant columns.

Composite unique indexes are created as,

```
add_index :association_table, [:table1_id, :table2_id], unique: true
```

Which will run faster queries like,

```
AssociationTable.where(table1_id: 34, table2_id: 54)
```

**Note-1** Order of columns in composite index matters so `AssociationTable.where(table2_id: 54, table1_id: 34)` does not run faster

**Note-2**  It makes no sense to have your `table_id1` and `table_id2` in separate indexes if you're also having a unique index of both columns

Comment: "so AssociationTable.where(table2_id: 54, table1_id: 34) does not run faster" - is that so? I'm quite sure that query planner can figure this out.

Comment: I will clear my idea first and update answer, Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Re note 2: it does make sense if they're querying by those fields alone. While the compound index will likely be sufficient to serve queries by table1_id, it will be less efficient (or inapplicable, depending on the database) for queries on table2_id.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev all this really depends on the DB and which kind of index is used. "A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns." -https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: @max: yes, that's what I said. Less efficient in postgres. But in, say, mongodb it isn't used at all.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Index on specific column in the table it helps you to speed up the query result with condition on that column.
Example: Single column index:

```
AssociationTable.where(:table1_id => 12)
```

In the above query single column(table1_id) indexing used to fetch the result quickly.

Creating an index on multiple columns in the table helps you to fetch the results quickly if you want filter by those columns.

Example: Multi column index:

```
AssociationTable.where(:table1_id => 12, :table2_id => 17)
```

In the above query multi column(table1_id, table2_id) indexing used to fetch the result quickly.

If you want to see the query analysis and indexing. Tools are available on each database clients like Mysql- Workbench query analyzer and Postgres - PgAdmin query analyzers are available. check with those to get practicle knowledge.